# Best practice for meteor dynamic subscription

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to do something like "filtered subscription" in Meteor: for example if you have a filter on month june and switching to july fetches the new data and subscribes to it?

i tried something like:

```
Meteor.publish("report", function (query, opt) {
    return Report.find({ 'timestamp' : { $gte : query.from, $lt: query.to }}, options);
}
```

on client with iron router:

```
HomeController=RouteController.extend({
    template:"home",
    waitOn:function(){
        var dates = getDates();
        return Meteor.subscribe("report", dates);
    },
    fastRender: true
});
```

but it does not work.

Is there a better method to dynamically subscribe? Or does it just help to navigate with url pattern?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better method to dynamically subscribe?

There is an alternative method using template subscriptions, example below.  I don't think it's better, just different.

> Or does it just help to navigate with url pattern?

If you want to handle the subscriptions in the Router, then storing the subscription query params in the URL does help and has some added benefits in my opinion.  But it depends on your desired app behavior.

Using [Template Subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) approach :

This Meteor Pad example will subscribe to a range of data based on a select : 
http://meteorpad.com/pad/26dd8YQevBbA5uNGA/Dynamic%20Subscription

Using Iron Router approach :

This route example will subscribe based on the URL .  "items/0/10" will subscribe to the itemData with a range of zero to 10.

```
Router.route('Items', {
  name:'Items',
  path:'items/:low/:high',
  subscriptions : function(){
    var low = parseInt(this.params.low);
    var high = parseInt(this.params.high);
    return [ 
      Meteor.subscribe("itemData",low,high),
    ];
  },
  action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    } else {
      this.render('Loading');
    }
  }    
});
```

I think either approach is fine and depends on your interface.  Using the URL is nice because you can provide links directly to the range of data, use forward and back buttons in browser, good for paging lists of data.
The template subscriptions approach might be appropriate to change the data on a graph.

The specific issue you are having might be due to the fact that your getDates() is not reactive, so the subscription is only run once when the route waitOn is first run.